# I can't pass the param after clicking the h:commandLink

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to create a quizz with data from a db but I'm a bit lost.

I have 3 tables :

- Quizz
- Questions (ManyToOne: Quizz)
- Answers (ManyToOne: Questions)

So I wrote this code to display each question with its answers:

```
        <p>Questions</p>
        <ui:repeat value="#{questionBean.fetchQuestionsFromQuizz(quizzBean.fetchQuizz(quizzBean.quizzId))}" var="i" varStatus="current">
            <p>#{i.question}</p>
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{i.selectedAnswerId}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{answerBean.fetchAnswersFromQuestion(i)}" var="item"
                               itemLabel="#{item.answer}" itemValue="#{item.id}" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </ui:repeat>
```

I'm getting the "quizzBean.quizzId" through a GET param.

The value of h:selectOneRadio is the selectedAnswerId property in my Question entity, so I'm trying to bind it with the selected answer by the user.

So I'm trying to pass the quizz id in the submit button to check them in the bean(@RequestScoped), but the quizz id is null once clicking on the submit button...

Here's the button:

```
<h:commandLink value="Submit" action="#{questionBean.checkTheAnswers()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{questionBean.fromQuizzId}" value="#{quizzBean.quizzId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

And here's the method (a simple print):

```
public void checkTheAnswers(){
    System.out.println("FROMQUIZZID : " + fromQuizzId);
}
```

So do you have any idea on why the quizzId is null?

Answer (score 0):

You have a requestScoped managed bean and you pass the quizzId using the http GET method, in this case you shoud initialize the quizzId filed with the value from the GET method using the @PostConstruct init method of the managedbean.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> params =  facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        if (params.containsKey("quizzId") {
            quizzId= params.get("quizzId");
        ....
```

Comment: _"you pass the quizzId using the http GET method"_ where did you get this impression?

Comment: Jeremy Dana said that "I'm getting the "quizzBean.quizzId" through a GET param."